# i % 2 == 0 ? arr[i] = 0 : arr[i] = 1; Ternary operator error

Tags: c, arrays, ternary-operator, lvalue

About ternary operator. I was rewriting an if-else statement in C, using the more clean ternary operator.
Here´s the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int arr[10];
    int i;

//    for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
//    {
//        if ( i % 2 == 0 )
//        {
//            arr[i] = 0;
//        }
//
//        else arr[i] = 1;
//    }

    for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
    {
         i % 2 == 0 ? arr[i] = 0 : arr[i] = 1;//Line in question
    }

    /* Just to check the result */
    for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
    {
        printf ( "%d ", arr[i] );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The commented code did work but for my surprise, when I compiled the file with the ternary operator, I got the following:

> C:\Users...\main.c|21|error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment|

This is a simple code to check weather the position in the array is odd or even.
Did a search and the only thing that I read that is related with this code is that the **lvalue** is a variable. If that is true I´m going to refer an example that to this day I haven't got an answer for:

```
printf ( "%d", 23 + 4 );
```

The placeholder is going to be replaced by the literal value of 27. No variable is involved here, it works tough.
Thank you.

Comment: ternary should be `variable = condition ? true_result : false_result`. doing assignments inside the result blocks is pretty nasty/ugly. e.g. `arr[i] = i % 2 == 0 ? 0 : 1`

Comment: Ternary operator isn't "more clean" than if-else. Your surprising error is demonstration of this fact.

Comment: At least in this case the ternary operator is not "more clean" than an `if`/`else` statement. It just makes the code harder to read (and, as you've seen, syntactically incorrect).

Comment: @Hurkyl It may be cleaner if used as suggested by Marc B.

Comment: I'm with Hurkyl and Keith Thompson. It's easier for the eye to follow `if...else` than to decode the ternary and for that reason I never use it.

Comment: Do not use the ternary operator as a *control structure* (i.e., to execute one or more *statements* based on the condition); that's not what it's meant for.  It leads to code that's harder to read and, as you've discovered, has some precedence issues.

Comment: @JohnBode: As you imply, the ternary operator does have its place. For example, `x = cond ? this : that;` avoids repeating `x`, particularly useful when `x` is `foo->bar[baz].thud`. It's also useful in macro definitions when you want the macro to expand to an expression.

Comment: @KeithThompson True it was syntactically wrong. I've been away for a long time from programming due to illness and I'm trying to get back on my feet. It's very hard right now to have an ideia and not being able to write it down, even tough it's a simple exercise. Still I find the ternary operator more clean indeed, specially in caeses when comparing the value of two variables (at least for me it was the first time that this control structure was presented to me). Just out of curiosity can you elaborate a bit more on both cases you suggest?

Comment: I think most C programmers will agree that the using the ternary operator when and `if`/`else` will do the same thing just makes the code more obscure. Using it within an expression can be useful if it means other parts of the same expression don't have to be repeated.

Comment: @KeithThompson I had a teacher who had an oposite idea. In this particular case the goal (wich I forgot to tell but I've just wrote it now, on the edit summary) was to write it all in one line of code. So I remebered this control structure.

Comment: @mxajd: Please do not take your teacher's advice seriously, at least not on this particular point. Figuring out how to write complex code in one line can be fun, but the result is difficult to read and difficult to maintain. Any given chunk of code will be read many more times than it's written, and likely modified multiple times as well. Optimize for clarity, not for terseness.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change:

```
i % 2 == 0 ? arr[i] = 0 : arr[i] = 1;
```

to this:

```
i % 2 == 0 ? (arr[i] = 0) : (arr[i] = 1);
```

The conditional operator has higher precedence than the assignment operator.

As suggested in the comments, you can get the same result with:

```
arr[i] = (i % 2 == 0 ? 0 : 1);
```

or simply:

```
arr[i] = i % 2;
```

Comment: Or, `arr[i] = <ternary op expression>` might be clearer.

Comment: @KeithThompson Yep, that one definitely wins.

Comment: @ouah Your expalnation is not clear to me: "The conditional operator has higher precedence than the assignment operator". 
That was my thought; first the condition is evaluated and then the assignment is done. Although I agree with a few of solutions by the users (way better than mine), I remember a few years ago, when I was shown the ternary operator for the 1st time, that the parentisis mattered. Just don't remeber when and in this case why.

Comment: @mxajd it means that an expression like `x ? y = a : y = b` is parsed as `(x ? (y = a) : y) = b` and not as `(x ? (y = a) : y) = b`

Comment: @mxajd "first the condition is evaluated and then the assignment is done." – you are confusing order of evaluation with precedence.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply it to :)

```
arr[i] = i%2;
```

Comment: Or better yet `i & 1` to correctly handle negative values, which admittedly aren't a problem in the original sample code.

Answer (score 1):

Due to operator precedence issues, I believe your code is getting parsed like this: `(i % 2 == 0 ? arr[i] = 0 : arr[i]) = 1;`. The ternary operator produces an `rvalue`, which, in C, cannot be assigned to. You should change it to `i % 2 == 0 ? (arr[i] = 0) : (arr[i] = 1);`

Anyway, this entire construct is superfluos, and should better be replaced with something like `arr[i] = i % 2;`

Answer (score 0):

Why not:

```
for (i=0; i < 10; i+=2)  {
    arr[i]   = 0;
    arr[i+1] = 1;
}
```

Comment: The challenge was to do it all in one line